# Android: Speedometer Style Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have been trying to make a layout for an Android app that functions like a car Speedometer.

Something like this:

[image: layout mockup]

I basically want there to be 5 clickable Views across the radius of the dial, and have the dial point to the currently selected item. If possible it would be good to be able to click and drag the dial. I would also want this layout to work nicely with different screen sizes and resolutions, including tablets.

How could something like this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly how much [this](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/) will help, but it goes over a similar design and shows how to place things at angles around a curve.

For each selectable view, I would also advise that you keep use keep track of the coordinates of each item, so you can use trig to calculate the proper angle for the dial to display (getting the dial to display at an angle is covered in that link).

[image: Trig]

So, you can set up `OnClickListener`s for each of your selectable items about the gauge, and in each instance, calculate the proper angle for the dial to spin to, and position it there using the information found in that link.

I'm not sure how much this helped, if at all, but it should at least give you an idea on creating custom `View`s and whatnot.

Good luck!